# Discrete time model

Tags: python

I'm presented with the following problem:

> For simplicity, let’s assume that there are only three options: Republican, Democrat, and Independent. Republican and Democrat are equally attractive (or annoying, maybe) to people, with no fundamental asymmetry between them. The popularities of Republican and Democrat ideologies can be represented by two variables, pr and pd, respectively (0 ≤ pr ≤ 1; 0 ≤ pd ≤ 1; 0≤ pr + pd ≤ 1). This implies that 1- pr - pd = pi represents the popularity of Independent. Assume that at each election poll, people will change their ideological states among the three options according to their relative popularities in the previous poll.
>
> For example, the rate of switching from option X to option Y can be considered proportional to (pY - pX) if pY > pX, or 0 otherwise. You should consider six different cases of such switching behaviors (Republican to Democrat, Republican to Independent, Democrat to Republican, Democrat to Independent, Independent to Republican, and Independent to Democrat) and represent them in dynamical equations.
>
> Complete a discrete-time mathematical model that describes this system, and simulate its behavior. See what the possible final outcomes are after a sufficiently long time period.

I have tried the following code in various ways to accomplish this problem, but run into the same problems such as:

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable;
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Code:

```
from pylab import *

max=()

def initialize():
    global pr, pd, pi, prresult, pdresult, piresult
    pr = 1.
    pd = 1.
    pi = 1.
    prresult = [pr]
    pdresult = [pd]
    piresult = [pi]
    
def observe():
    global pr, pd, pi, prresult, pdresult, piresult
    prresult.append(pr)
    pdresult.append(pd)
    piresult.append(pi)

def update():
    global pr, pd, pi, prresult, pdresult, piresult
    nextpr = pr + max(pr - pd,0) * pd + max(pr - pi,0) * pi - max(pd - pr,0) * pr - max(pi - pr,0) * pr
    nextpd = pd + max(pd - pr,0) * pr + max(pd - pi,0) * pi - max(pr - pd,0) * pd - max(pi - pd,0) * pd
    pr, pd, pi = nextpr, nextpd, nextpi

initialize()
for t in range(100):
    update()
    observe()

plot(rresult, 'm-')
plot(dresult, 'g--')
plot(iresult, 'y-.')
show()
```

Comment: Please format the code - select it and type `ctrl-k`.
.. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Answer (score 0):

It's not working but the main problem is gone. The line `max=()` is overwriting the max function. So when it's used later is not a function but a tuple.

Also I write this formula based on the other ones but can be wrong.

```
nextpi = (
    pi
    + max(pi - pr, 0) * pr
    + max(pi - pi, 0) * pi
    - max(pr - pi, 0) * pi
    - max(pi - pi, 0) * pi
)
```

Now, if you provide more info about this lines I can take a look.

```
plot(rresult, "m-")
plot(dresult, "g--")
plot(iresult, "y-.")
from pylab import *
```

Resulting code:

```
from pylab import *


def initialize():
    global pr, pd, pi, prresult, pdresult, piresult
    pr = 1.0
    pd = 1.0
    pi = 1.0
    prresult = [pr]
    pdresult = [pd]
    piresult = [pi]


def observe():
    global pr, pd, pi, prresult, pdresult, piresult
    prresult.append(pr)
    pdresult.append(pd)
    piresult.append(pi)


def update():
    global pr, pd, pi, prresult, pdresult, piresult
    nextpr = (
        pr
        + max(pr - pd, 0) * pd
        + max(pr - pi, 0) * pi
        - max(pd - pr, 0) * pr
        - max(pi - pr, 0) * pr
    )
    nextpd = (
        pd
        + max(pd - pr, 0) * pr
        + max(pd - pi, 0) * pi
        - max(pr - pd, 0) * pd
        - max(pi - pd, 0) * pd
    )

    nextpi = (
        pi
        + max(pi - pr, 0) * pr
        + max(pi - pi, 0) * pi
        - max(pr - pi, 0) * pi
        - max(pi - pi, 0) * pi
    )
    pr, pd, pi = nextpr, nextpd, nextpi


initialize()
for t in range(100):
    update()
    observe()

plot(rresult, "m-")
plot(dresult, "g--")
plot(iresult, "y-.")
show()
```

Comment: plot(rresult, "m-"); plot(dresult, "g--"); plot(iresult, "y-.") was a miss type each one is missing p.  For instance, "rresult" should have been "prresult". The point of these lines was to graph each function in a different color.

Comment: There is no rresult in the code you provided, are there any error left?

Comment: Not that I can tell. It shows everything in one straight line, but I'm pretty sure that's not correct. So, I'm not sure where to go from here at this point.